# Give the smallest number from the for loop and make switch infinite

Tags: c++

1. I don't know how to show the smallest number from the range which user has given and remember that these numbers must be even.
2. Before switch I added for(;;) to make this switch infinite but as a result it gives me infinite answers to one of the cases. I want to go back to the beggining of the case and have option to choose.

Here is the code:

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int number1, number2;
    std::cout << "Give first number: ";
    std::cin >> number1;
    std::cout << "Give second number: ";
    std::cin >> number2;

    while (number1 > number2) {
        std::cout << std::endl;
        std::cout << "First number must be smaller than the second number!\n";
        std::cout << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Give first number: ";
        std::cin >> number1;
        std::cout << "Give second number ";
        std::cin >> number2;
    }

    std::cout << std::endl;

    int choice, quantity = 0, sum = 0, table[1000];

    std::cout << "MENU:\n";
    std::cout << "1. Show even numbers from the smallest to the largest.\n";
    std::cout << "2. Show even numbers from the largest to the smallest.\n";
    std::cout << "3. Show the amount of even numbers.\n";
    std::cout << "4. Show the sum of even numbers.\n";
    std::cout << "5. Show the average of even numbers.\n";
    std::cout << "6. Show the smallest number of even numbers.\n";
    std::cout << "7. Exit.\n";
    std::cout << "Choose number: ";
    std::cin >> choice;

    std::cout << std::endl;

    for(;;) {

        switch (choice) {
        case 1: 
            for (int i = number1; i <= number2; i++) {
                if (i % 2 == 0) std::cout << i << std::endl;
            }
            break;
        case 2: 
            for (int i = number2; i >= number1; i--) {
                if (i % 2 == 0) std::cout << i << std::endl;
            }
            break;
        case 3:
            quantity = (number2 - number1) / 2;
            quantity++;
            std::cout << quantity << std::endl;
            break;
        case 4:
            for (int i = number1; i <= number2; i++) {
                if (i % 2 == 0) sum = sum + i;
            }
            std::cout << sum << std::endl;
            break;
        case 5:
            quantity = (number2 - number1) / 2;
            quantity++;
            for (int i = number1; i <= number2; i++) {
                if (i % 2 == 0) sum = sum + i;
            }
            std::cout << sum / quantity << std::endl;
            break;
        case 6:
            for (int i = number1; i <= number2; i++) {
                if (i % 2 == 0) {
                    table[i];
                }
            }
            std::cout << table[1] << std::endl;
        case 7:
            exit(0);    
            break;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: the `std::cin` call to take user input is outside the loop which evaluates it. I also recommend you change the `for(;;)` to a `while(flag)`, and set the `flag` to `false` instead of making the `exit(0)` call in the loop so you have proper control of the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The simplest way is to just look at the lowest number the user has entered.  If it is even, it is already the smallest even number.  If it is odd, increment it by 1 (if it does not exceed the highest number the user has entered) and that is the smallest even number.
2. you need to move your menu output and prompt for user input INSIDE the `for` loop, instead of BEFORE the `for` loop.

Try something like this:

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>

int sumOfEvens(int lowest, int highest)
{
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = lowest; i <= highest; i++) {
        if (i % 2 == 0) sum += i;
    }
    return sum;
}

int quantityOfEvens(int lowest, int highest)
{
    if (lowest == highest) return (lowest % 2 == 0) ? 1 : 0;
    int quantity = diff / 2;
    if (diff % 2 != 0) ++quantity;
    return quantity;
}

int smallestEven(int lowest, int highest)
{
    if (lowest % 2 == 0) return lowest;
    if (lowest < highest) return lowest + 1;
    return -1;
}

int main()
{
    int number1, number2, lowest, highest;
    int choice, quantity, smallest;

    std::cout << "Give first number: ";
    std::cin >> number1;

    std::cout << "Give second number: ";
    std::cin >> number2;

    lowest = (number1 < number2) ? number1 : number2;
    highest = (number1 < number2) ? number2 : number1;

    do
    {
        std::cout << "MENU:\n";
        std::cout << "1. Show even numbers from the smallest to the largest.\n";
        std::cout << "2. Show even numbers from the largest to the smallest.\n";
        std::cout << "3. Show the amount of even numbers.\n";
        std::cout << "4. Show the sum of even numbers.\n";
        std::cout << "5. Show the average of even numbers.\n";
        std::cout << "6. Show the smallest number of even numbers.\n";
        std::cout << "7. Exit.\n";
        std::cout << "Choose number: ";
        std::cin >> choice; 

        std::cout << std::endl;

        switch (choice) {
        case 1: 
            for (int i = lowest; i <= highest; i++) {
                if (i % 2 == 0) std::cout << i << std::endl;
            }
            break;

        case 2: 
            for (int i = highest; i >= lowest; i--) {
                if (i % 2 == 0) std::cout << i << std::endl;
            }
            break;

        case 3:
            std::cout << quantityOfEvens(lowest, highest) << std::endl;
            break;

        case 4:
            std::cout << sumOfEvens(lowest, highest) << std::endl;
            break;

        case 5:
            quantity = quantityOfEvens(lowest, highest);
            if (quantity != 0) std::cout << sumOfEvens(lowest, highest) / quantity;
            std::cout << std::endl;
            break;

        case 6:
            smallest = smallestEven(lowest, highest);
            if (smallest != -1) std:cout << smallest;
            cout << std::endl;
            break;
    }
    while (choice != 7);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you write for me part of code which should I write using std::vector? I don’t understand it at all

Comment: @OliwierPiasecki no `vector` needed, I updated my answer